# How do I sort the contents of every file using ls?

Tags: c

Currently I'm piping ls (within the first child) to sort (within the second child), but sort is reading the output of ls as one line instead of different file names

In my code, I have for the first child:

```
if(childpid == 0){
    close(fd[0]);
    dup2(fd[1], 1);
    execlp("ls", "ls", (char *)0);
}
```

Now for the second child, it should be reading the output of the first child:

```
if(childpid2 == 0){
    close(fd[1]);
    dup2(fd[0], 0);
    read(fd[0], string, sizeof(string));
    close(fd[0]);
    execlp("sort", "sort", string, NULL);
}
```

My current output is:

```
sort: open failed: activity
text.txt
text2.txt
exercise.c
: File name too long
```

Is there a way that I can have each file read separately so that sort can look at the contents within each file to sort them?

Comment: You're not piping anything to `sort`, you read the data yourself and pass it to `sort` as a string. `sort` interprets that as a file name. It cannot open the file name of `"activity\ntext.txt\n...."` because it's too long.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. I'll try and redo my piping process, thank you